# Upgrading Entity Framework 4.3.1 to 5.0.0 beta 1 gives binding redirects error

Tags: entity-framework

My solution uses Entity Framework 4.3.1. I want to upgrade to 5.0.0 beta-1. The package manager gives the following output:

```
PM> Install-Package -IncludePrerelease EntityFramework
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is   available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=242870. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0-beta1'.
Successfully removed 'EntityFramework 4.3.1' from PROJECTNAME.
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 5.0.0-beta1' to PROJECTNAME.
Failed to generate binding redirects for 'PROJECTNAME'. 'object' does not contain a definition for 'References'
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 4.3.1'.
```

It looks like the upgrade completed succesfully, but I wonder how I could have prevented this error.

Comment: I think this is more of a general NuGet error. I also see it when I try to install packages into a solution with WiX projects in it.

Comment: I agree with Brice--can you file a bug for it with NuGet? http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Answer (score 0):

You should enable automatic binding redirection manually. To do this:

1. In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, right-click the project and choose "Unload Project".
2. Add the following element to the property group (under the  tag) in XML code:

   ```
   <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
   ```

The following shows an example project file with the element inserted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{123334}</ProjectGuid>
    ...
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ...
</Project>
```

3. Right click the project and choose "Reload Project".
4. Compile your app.
5. List item
6. Install EntityFramework.